# Using syntethica in my maven project (Netbeans IDE 7.2.1)

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, look-and-feel

I'm new into programming on java and having some problems with adding syntethica LaF to my Maven project. I'm using Netbeans IDE 7.2.1. I think, syntethica.jar should appear in dependencies list, right? I've tried to manually add JAR file into local repository and it seemed to be successful added, but it isn't appear in dependencies list. How can I add syntethica.jar to my project so I could use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a dependency group in your `pom.xml`. Something like:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>something...synthetica</groupId>
    <artifactId>somethingother...synthetica</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3.4.5.6</version>
</dependency>
```

I couldn't find synthetica in central, and judging from you mentioning localrepository, you should

- match the groupId, artifactId and version to your localrepository structure and
- add your localrepository as a `<repository>...` in your POM

Cheers,